# Dynamic Add and Edit of Data in Asp.net Mvc using Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dapper

I'm new to MVC. Using the scaffolding mechanism I have managed to create CRUD operations on the database table. This works well with working on a single MVC Model at a time (Mapped to a single Model). I want to implement add & edit of a List into database (will be empty list initially), the user should be able to add as many number of items as he need and then submit the data to the database. I want this list to be of dynamic length, so that when user edits the data he should be able to add few more new elements into the Model also deleting few individual Model. I couldn't find proper resource to come up with a solution. Little help will be much Appreciated.

Scenario - Person can have multiple Addresses or Person will not be having any addresses. How to add multiple Address by adding addresses into the view and how to perform edit on those? If one of the Address needs to be deleted then how to do so?

Thank you.

**Here is My View:**

```
@model MVC.Models.PersonDetailsViewModel
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "AddorEdit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">

        <div id="personDetails" class="row">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.personModel.PersonId, new { @id = "personId" })

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <div style="display:inline">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <div style="display:inline;">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                    <div style="display:inline">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.DateOfBirth, new { @id = "dob", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>Height</label>
                    <div style="display:inline">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.Height, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.Height, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>Weight</label>
                    <div style="display:inline">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.Weight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.Weight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <div style="display:inline">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.personModel.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personModel.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="tabs" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Address</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">Insuarance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab">Emergency Contacts</a></li>
                </ul><br />
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content panel-body">
                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div style="height:22px">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd" style="float:right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add New Row</a>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="mainContent">
                        <div id="addressDiv">
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                @*@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.addressModel);*@
                                @{
                                    Html.RenderAction("AddressPartialView", "Person");
                                }
                            </div>
                            <a id="closeAddress" style="margin-top:33px" class="col-md-1 closeLink"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></i></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.insuranceModel.InsuranceId, new { @id = "insuranceId" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Health Plan</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.insuranceModel.HealthPlan, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.insuranceModel.HealthPlan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Health Plan Type</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.insuranceModel.HealthPlanType, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.insuranceModel.HealthPlanType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Card Number</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.insuranceModel.CardNumber, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.insuranceModel.CardNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-pane fade">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.EmergencyContactId, new { @id = "emergencyContactId" })
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Contact Patient</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @{
                                List<SelectListItem> personItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                                personItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select One--", Value = "", Selected = true });
                                personItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
                                personItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
                                personItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
                                personItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
                            }
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.ContactPersonId, personItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.ContactPersonId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Relationship Type</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @{
                                List<SelectListItem> relationshipItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select One--", Value = "", Selected = true });
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Father", Value = "Father" });
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mother", Value = "Mother" });
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Son", Value = "Son" });
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Daughter", Value = "Daughter" });
                                relationshipItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Guardian", Value = "Guardian" });
                            }
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.RelationshipType, relationshipItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.RelationshipType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.ContactNumber, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Email Id</label>
                        <div style="display:inline">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.EmailId, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emergencyContactModel.EmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:10px" />
        </div>

    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**And here are my Controller Methods:**

```
public ActionResult AddressPartialView()
        {
            var _model = new PersonDetailsViewModel();
            return PartialView("_Address", _model.addressModel);
        }

//To load the data into the form - for editing
public ActionResult AddorEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                var myModel = new PersonDetailsViewModel();
                return View(myModel);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responsePerson = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Person/" + id.ToString()).Result;
                HttpResponseMessage responseAddress = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Address/" + id.ToString()).Result;
                HttpResponseMessage responseInsurance = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Insurance/" + id.ToString()).Result;
                HttpResponseMessage responseEmergencyContact = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("EmergencyContact/" + id.ToString()).Result;
                var personJsonString = responsePerson.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MvcPersonModel>>(personJsonString.Result);
                var addressJsonString = responseAddress.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedAddress = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MvcAddressModel>>(addressJsonString.Result);
                var insuranceJsonString = responseInsurance.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedInsurance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MvcInsuranceModel>>(insuranceJsonString.Result);
                var emergencyContactJsonString = responseEmergencyContact.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedEmergencyContact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MvcEmergencyContactModel>>(emergencyContactJsonString.Result);

                var _ViewModel = new PersonDetailsViewModel();
                _ViewModel.personModel = deserializedPerson.FirstOrDefault();
                _ViewModel.addressModel = deserializedAddress.FirstOrDefault();
                _ViewModel.insuranceModel = deserializedInsurance.FirstOrDefault();
                _ViewModel.emergencyContactModel = deserializedEmergencyContact.FirstOrDefault();

                return View(_ViewModel);
            }
        }


//Posting data to the database
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddorEdit(PersonDetailsViewModel viewModel)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responsePerson = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Person", viewModel.personModel).Result;
    HttpResponseMessage responseAddress = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Address", viewModel.addressModel).Result;
    HttpResponseMessage responseInsurance = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Insurance", viewModel.insuranceModel).Result;
    HttpResponseMessage responseEmergencyContact = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("EmergencyContact", viewModel.emergencyContactModel).Result;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I'm using Web API for the backend process. I have added a delete and Add New Row button in the view for **Address** tab. For now it is working with just a single Model, I wanted to know how to implement it for a Dynamic list, So as to A Person can have 'n' number of Addresses and he can edit whichever he want and also delete based on AddressId. I know the code seems quite low rated. Just want to know the syntax and semantics on how to proceed with working on List. Sorry for Messing up things. Thank you.

Comment: Could we see what you've done so far?

Comment: look for jquery repeater, add repeater to your forms, and submit using ajax, this will work

Comment: I looked into jquery repeater, It seems like repeats the html elements? If using that how to achieve binding of controls to a List<Model> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from Matt lunn.

Follow this link :- 
https://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

It is implemented by using custom **HtmlHelper** Extension and creating **Html.EditorForMany()**.

Thanks a lot for the trick [Matt Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt). Works Exactly How I wanted. :)